# Add comma between elements

Tags: r

I took a vector from a dataframe and it looks like this:

```
df <- dataframe$ghcnd
```

### Grabbing necessary column

This gives me an output like:

```
[1] "GHCND:US1AKAB0058" "GHCND:US1AKAB0015" "GHCND:US1AKAB0021" "GHCND:US1AKAB0061"
   [5] "GHCND:US1AKAB0055" "GHCND:US1AKAB0038" "GHCND:US1AKAB0051" "GHCND:US1AKAB0052"
   [9] "GHCND:US1AKAB0060" "GHCND:US1AKAB0065" "GHCND:US1AKAB0062" "GHCND:US1AKFN0016"
```

I have done the following to add a comma between the entries:

```
df2 <- paste("'",df,"'",collapse = ",")
```

However, that gives me this:

```
[1] "GHCND:US1AKAB0058,GHCND:US1AKAB0015,GHCND:US1AKAB0021,GHCND:US1AKAB0061,GHCND:US1AKAB0055,GHCND:US1AKAB0038,GHCND:US1AKAB0051,GHCND:US1AKAB0052,GHCND:US1AKAB0060,GHCND:US1AKAB0065,GHCND:US1AKAB0062,GHCND:US1AKFN0016,GHCND:US1AKFN0018,GHCND:US1AKFN0015,GHCND:US1AKFN0011,GHCND:US1AKFN0013"
```

I need to preserve the quotes around each individual weather station code. Instead, this method is only keeping the first and last quotation marks.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try `paste("'", df, "'", sep="", collapse=",")`

Comment: Oh this answered it, thanks!

I didn't give me the aesthetic I was looking for but it turned out to not matter.  Its not giving me the option to click the green check button for some reason though!